# You don't have permission to access /~iMac/ on this server. apache server

Tags: apache, localhost

I am trying to use apache localhost
localhost works normally but http://localhost/~iMac/ give me the error in the title.

this is how I proceed:
 i added a Sites folder under iMac
create file imac.conf under /etc/apache2/users

```
<Directory "/Users/imac/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I also tried `AllowOverride All`

I uncomment tese lines in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

and uncomment this line in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf
```

and then restart the server.

I tried lots of solution in the net but still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but I solved it by setting the options directive either in the global directory setting in the httpd.conf or in the specific directory block in httpd-vhosts.conf:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
By default, your global directory settings is (httpd.conf line ~188):

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

set the options to : Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

Finally, it should look like:

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also, you should check the folder's permissions so that the Apache process' owner has permissions to read/execute the specified path for the virtual host. On Windows this could rarely be a problem but on Linux it can be a more frequent cause of 403.

EDIT: You can look here for some solution also if you are hosting this on a Mac:
http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/forbidden-403-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-username-on-this-server/

Comment: IThank you, I tried your solution and no change this is Sites' folder permessions: "drwxr-xr-x  2 iMac  staff  68 11 mar 10:23 Sites"

Comment: I changed the Sites' folder permissin to "drwxrwxrwx  2 iMac  staff  68 11 mar 10:23 Sites" but still not working :(